# Webpack publicPath don't work

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I have a demo like this:
    my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: './build',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /static\.html/,
      use: 'file-loader'
    }, {
      test: /\.png/,
      use: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
    }, {
      test: /\.css/,
      use: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
    }],
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['node_modules'],
  }
}
```

this is my entry app.js:

```
import './static.html';
import './img.png';
import './index.css';
```

static.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>static</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index.css">
</head>
<body>
  <img src="./img.png">
</body>
</html>
```

when i run npm run build, i got a build folder. I think the build/static.html should be

```
<img src="http://localhost:3000/img.png"> 
<link href="http://localhost:3000/index.css">
```

But, actually the build/static.html is the same as static.html. Both of the src of img and the href of link are not changed.

Any one knows why?

====

I have known the answer. Webpack publicPath just work for output file. So just the url in the bundle.js will be replaced.

The webpackHtmlPlugin will not resolve this problem, because this plugin will generate a html page with a script links to the output bundle.js that I don't need it.

To resolve this problem, I have wrote a custom loader to transform the html page output by the file-loader dynamicly.

Answer (score 0):

The `file-loader` would not change the file. If you want a html file with the `publicPath` added, you should use [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin).